# Can cross-validation be involved in model-building rather than validation?

Tags: regression, cross-validation, model-selection, predictor

I have a general idea in mind that would go like this:

1. randomly split the data into training/testing
2. build a model on the training data by choosing from among candidate predictors
3. evaluate it on the testing data
4. repeat n times

Find the model that did the best job predicting the testing data.

In this way, cross-validation is involved in the model-building stage.

Is there a name for this approach that I can Google (and hopefully find an R package for)?

I am aware of some similar approaches:

**Best Subsets** will try every possible regression model and find the best one. However, as far as I am aware, this process doesn't involve cross-validation.

**LASSO** uses cross-validation to optimize tuning parameters, but not for variable selection per se.

**Random Forests** will again try various combinations of predictors, but afaik doesn't involve cross-validation in the process.

Comment: Look up "Nested Cross Validation"